# Pyspark: how to split a dataframe into chunks and save them?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I need to split a `pyspark` dataframe `df` and save the different chunks.

This is what I am doing: I define a column `id_tmp` and I split the dataframe based on that.

```
  chunk = 10000
  id1 = 0
  id2 = chunk
  df = df.withColumn('id_tmp', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())) - 1)
  c = df.count()
  while id1 < c:
    stop_df = df.filter( (tmp.id_tmp < id2) & (tmp.id_tmp >= id1))
    stop_df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('myFolder/')
    id1+=chunk
    id2+=chunk
```

Is there a more efficient way without defining the column `id_tmp`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use the `partitionBy` method from the `DataFrameWriter` interface built-in Spark ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.partitionBy)). Here is an example.

Given the `df` DataFrame, the chuck identifier needs to be one or more columns. In my example `id_tmp`. The following snippet generates a DF with 12 records with 4 chunk ids.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.range(0, 12).withColumn("id_tmp", F.col("id") % 4).orderBy("id_tmp")
df.show()
```

Returns:

```
+---+------+
| id|id_tmp|
+---+------+
|  8|     0|
|  0|     0|
|  4|     0|
|  1|     1|
|  9|     1|
|  5|     1|
|  6|     2|
|  2|     2|
| 10|     2|
|  3|     3|
| 11|     3|
|  7|     3|
+---+------+
```

To save each chunk indepedently you need:

```
(df
 .repartition("id_tmp")
 .write
 .partitionBy("id_tmp")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .format("csv")
 .save("output_folder"))
```

`repartition` will shuffle the records so that each node has a complete set of records for one "id_tmp" value. Then each chunk is written to one file with the `partitionBy`.

Resulting folder structure:

```
output_folder/
output_folder/._SUCCESS.crc
output_folder/id_tmp=0
output_folder/id_tmp=0/.part-00000-eba244a4-ce95-4f4d-b9b8-8e5f972b144f.c000.csv.crc
output_folder/id_tmp=0/part-00000-eba244a4-ce95-4f4d-b9b8-8e5f972b144f.c000.csv
output_folder/id_tmp=1
output_folder/id_tmp=1/.part-00000-eba244a4-ce95-4f4d-b9b8-8e5f972b144f.c000.csv.crc
output_folder/id_tmp=1/part-00000-eba244a4-ce95-4f4d-b9b8-8e5f972b144f.c000.csv
output_folder/id_tmp=2
output_folder/id_tmp=2/.part-00000-eba244a4-ce95-4f4d-b9b8-8e5f972b144f.c000.csv.crc
output_folder/id_tmp=2/part-00000-eba244a4-ce95-4f4d-b9b8-8e5f972b144f.c000.csv
output_folder/id_tmp=3
output_folder/id_tmp=3/.part-00000-eba244a4-ce95-4f4d-b9b8-8e5f972b144f.c000.csv.crc
output_folder/id_tmp=3/part-00000-eba244a4-ce95-4f4d-b9b8-8e5f972b144f.c000.csv
output_folder/_SUCCESS
```

The size and number of partitions are quite important for Spark's performance. Don't partition the dataset too much and have reasonable file sizes (like 1GB per file) especially if you are using cloud storage services. It is also advised to use the partition variables if you want to filter the data when loading (i.e.: year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD)